# Control Guid format in ASP.NET Core action's response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-2.2

Suppose my ASP.NET Core (API) action returns an object with this property:

```
[WhatGoesHere("N")]                  // ?
public Guid MyGuid { get; set; }
```

It will be serialized as `ffd76e47-609f-42bc-b6b8-b66dedab5561`.

I want it to be serialized as `ffd76e47609f42bcb6b8b66dedab5561`. In code that would be `myGuid.ToString("N")`.

Is there an attribute I can use to control the formatting?

Comment: You can replace your '-' value to '' and you get the string as per your requirements.

Comment: @A.M.Patel I think you're missing the point. OP wants this to happen automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement a custom JsonConverter [see here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm). And configure your aspnet core application to register this JsonConverter for output formatting. This way every time your application would serialize a Guid to JSON you'll get it the way you want it:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options => {
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new MyCustomConverter());
    });
}
```

You can also choose some particular classes to use the converter instead of all of them, by using this attribute on top of it:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyCustomConverter))]
public class MyClass
{
    public Guid MyGuid { get;set; }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Check out my answer below for an implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @r1verside's answer, here is my implementation:

```
using System;

namespace MyProject {

  public sealed class GuidConverter : JsonConverter<Guid> {

    public GuidConverter() { }

    public GuidConverter(string format) { _format = format; }

    private readonly string _format = "N";

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Guid value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
      writer.WriteValue(value.ToString(_format));
    }

    public override Guid ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Guid existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
      string s = (string)reader.Value;
      return new Guid(s);
    }

  }
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(GuidConverter))]    // defaults to format of "N"
public Guid MyGuid { get; set; }
```

but format can be overridden:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(GuidConverter), "X")]
public Guid MyGuid { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

For a simple scenario like yours, the easiest way to do this is to have another property which formats the `MyGuid` by using `MyGuid.ToString("N")`. Where "N" means that you just need the digits without "-". Please see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tostring?view=netframework-4.8)

You can add `[JsonIgnore]` to the `MyGuid` and add `[JsonProperty("MyGuid")]` attribute to the other property:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Guid MyGuid { get;set; }

    [JsonProperty("MyGuid")]
    public string DisplayGuid => MyGuid.ToString("N");
}
```

With the above in place, `MyGuid` property will be ignored. Instead, `DisplayGuid` property will be returned with the name `MyGuid` with the value `ffd76e47609f42bcb6b8b66dedab5561`

For more complex scenarios, you can surely go for a custom JsonConverter option as mentioned by @r1verside. I hope this helps

Comment: Interesting idea, that doesn't require implementation of a converter... thanks!